# Problems on injecting into printf using LD_PRELOAD method

Tags: hook, code-injection, glibc

I was hacking printf() of glibc in one of my project and encountered some problem. Could you please give some clues? And one of my concern is why the same solution for malloc/free works perfect!

As attached, “PrintfHank.c” contains my own solution of printf() which will be preloaded before standard library; and “main.c” just outputs a sentence using printf(). After editing two files, I issued following commands:

1. compile main.c
           **gcc –Wall –o main main.c**
2. create my own library
           **gcc –Wall –fPIC –shared –o PrintfHank.so PrintfHank.c –ldl**
3. test the new library
           **LD_PRELOAD=”$mypath/PrintfHank.so” $mypath/main**

But I received “hello world” instead of “within my own printf” in the console. When hacking malloc/free functions, it’s okay.

I log in my system as “root” and am using 2.6.23.1-42.fc8-i686. Any comments will be highly appreciated!!

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello world\n");

    return 0;
}
```

PrintfHank.c

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

static int (*orig_printf)(const char *format, ...) = NULL;

int printf(const char *format, ...)
{
 if (orig_printf == NULL)
 {
  orig_printf = (int (*)(const char *format, ...))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "printf");
 }

 // TODO: print desired message from caller. 
 return orig_printf("within my own printf\n");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This question is ancient, however:

In your `main.c`, you've got a newline at the end and aren't using any of the formatting capability of `printf`.

If I look at the output of `LD_DEBUG=all LD_PRELOAD=./printhack.so hello 2>&1` (I've renamed your files somewhat), then near the bottom I can see

```
 17246:     transferring control: ./hello
 17246:     
 17246:     symbol=puts;  lookup in file=./hello [0]
 17246:     symbol=puts;  lookup in file=./printhack.so [0]
 17246:     symbol=puts;  lookup in file=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]
 17246:     binding file ./hello [0] to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `puts' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
```

and no actual mention of `printf`. `puts` is basically printf without the formatting and with an automatic line break at the end, so this evidently the result of gcc being "helpful" by replacing the `printf` with a `puts`.

To make your example work, I removed the `\n` from the `printf`, which gives me output like:

```
 17114:     transferring control: ./hello
 17114:     
 17114:     symbol=printf;  lookup in file=./hello [0]
 17114:     symbol=printf;  lookup in file=./printhack.so [0]
 17114:     binding file ./hello [0] to ./printhack.so [0]: normal symbol `printf' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
```

Now I can see that `printhack.so` is indeed being dragged in with its custom `printf`.

Alternatively, you can define a custom `puts` function as well:

```
static int (*orig_puts)(const char *str) = NULL;
int puts(const char *str)
{
    if (orig_puts == NULL)
    {
        orig_puts = (int (*)(const char *str))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "puts");
    }

    // TODO: print desired message from caller.
    return orig_puts("within my own puts");
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn off gcc from changing function printf() to puts() ?

Comment: This question may be ancient, but this answer is still useful 12.5 years after the question was asked! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check 
1) preprocessor output. printf can be changed to smth else

```
gcc -E main.c
```

2) ld_debug info about printf symbol and preloading

```
LD_DEBUG=help LD_PRELOAD=”$mypath/PrintfHank.so” $mypath/main
LD_DEBUG=all LD_PRELOAD=”$mypath/PrintfHank.so” $mypath/main
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return orig_printf("within my own printf\n");
```

to

```
return (*orig_printf)("within my own printf\n");
```