# ld_preload printf to use stderr instead of stdout

Tags: c, unix, printf, ld-preload

I am trying to hook `printf` function in c and implement a very similar function only that it prints to `stderr` stream.

printf code:

```
int printf (const char *format, ...)
{
   va_list arg;
   int done;

   va_start (arg, format);
   done = vfprintf (stdout, format, arg);
   va_end (arg);

   return done;
}
```

I changed stdout to stderr but when running with `> /dev/null` (which redirects `stdout` to null) I still don't see the output. When running ltrace I can see it calls puts instead of printf, I think this is the problem.

Comment: If you are calling printf with a string literal then the compiler optmises it out to puts() call. Try with something that requires format string parsing (e.g. `int x=5; printf("%d\n", x*x);`. You still call vfprintf with stdout? Have you verified your preloaded library is actually loaded (try with simple `write(1, "hi", 2);` in your hook)?

Comment: Is it okay to redirect everything from `stdout` to `stderr`?  If so and if you are using bash, just write `myprog arg1 arg2 argN 1>&2`.  That last `1>&2` part will redirect `stdout` to `stderr`.  See [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html).

Comment: Why not just `fprintf(stderr, ....)`? Trying to write a replacement function for a library function is not always as simple as just writing a same-named function...

Answer (score 1):

According to ISO/IEC 9899:201x redefining an reserved identifier like `printf` results in undefined behaviour:

> 7.1.3.2 ... If  the  program  declares  or  defines  an  identifier  in  a context  in  which  it  is  reserved  (other  than  as  allowed 
>   by  7.1.4),  or  defines  a  reserved identifier as a macro name, the
>   behavior is undefined.

So like P.P. pointed out it is totally legal for the compiler to optimize certain calls to `printf` by replacing them with `puts` because the observable behaviour is the same if `printf` is not redefined and UB rules (meaning anything can happen) apply if you redefine it.

Answer (score 0):

so I figured it out.. the code above was fine, the preload was fine, and as I said for some reason puts was called instead of printf. The simple Hello World program that demonstrated LD_PRELOAD looked like this:

```
printf("Hello World\n");
```

when I removed the \n it worked fine, and puts was not called! 
more about this issue can be found here: [Problems on injecting into printf using LD_PRELOAD method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576689/problems-on-injecting-into-printf-using-ld-preload-method)